# TensorFlow - TFRecords load and transform images with bounding boxes

Tags: tensorflow, image-classification, transfer-learning

I'm trying to build a 'Car Classifier' using TensorFlow.

I have 1000 labelled JPG images, 800x800, complete with bounding boxes and associated annotations.coco.json; split into train/validate/test folders.

I've managed to load the TFRecordDataset's using the code below:

**TFRecord Data Set Loading Steps**

```
# Load TfRecord data sets
raw_train = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([training_file])
raw_validation = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([validation_file])
raw_test = tf.data.TFRecordDataset([testing_file])

# Load label map
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(label_map_file, use_display_name=True)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def extract_features(tfrecord):
    # Extract features using the keys set during creation
    features = {
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32),        
        'image/object/class/label': tf.io.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),        
        'image/width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'image/height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'image/encoded': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }

    # Extract the data record
    sample = tf.io.parse_single_example(tfrecord, features)

    image = tf.io.decode_image(sample['image/encoded'])        
    label = sample['image/object/class/label']
        
    return [image, label]

raw_train = raw_train.map(extract_features)
raw_validation = raw_validation.map(extract_features)
raw_test = raw_test.map(extract_features)
```

**Transform/Resize images for Training**

```
ORIGINAL_IMG_SIZE = 800
RESIZE_IMG_SIZE = 160 # All images will be resized to 160x160 or 614x614 maybe for Yolo?

def format_example(image, label):
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62957726/i-got-value-error-that-image-has-no-shape-while-converting-image-to-tensor-for-p
    image.set_shape([ORIGINAL_IMG_SIZE, ORIGINAL_IMG_SIZE, 3])
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = (image/127.5) - 1
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (RESIZE_IMG_SIZE, RESIZE_IMG_SIZE))
    return image, label
```

- Tensorflow examples only seem to talk about resizing the whole image and not about how to handle resizing of bounding boxes within the image, and bounding box labels.
- **Does anyone have any examples of how to handle the resizing of images together with bounding boxes contained within the image?**

**Training Pipeline**

- Again Tensorflow examples only seem to train with whole images, not with images with bounding boxes and associated bounding box labels.
- **Does anyone have any examples of TensorFlow Transfer Learning training with images with bounding boxes and associated bounding box labels?**